# Creating custom error page in apache

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-404

I created a custom 404 error page.

```
<h1>Page not found</h1>
```

But when I reload/restart apache2 it gives me this:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 234 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/errors/404.html: /etc/apache2/conf.d/errors/404.html:1: <h1>Page> was not closed.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Can anyone say what's the problem ?

Comment: On line 234 is: Include conf.d/

Comment: can u show conf.d file? have used ErrorDocument? It takes in a absolute URL path instead of a file path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in /etc/apache2/conf.d/errors/404.html file you have not closed <h1>  tag properly. Try below.

<h1>Page</h1>

Please notice </h1> here.

Comment: As you can see I closed it.